# How to extract last X digits from fixed Y digit number using RegEx?

Tags: java, regex, tibco-business-works

How to extract last X digits from fixed Y digit number using RegEx?

input : `1234567890123456`

- `((?=\d{16}$)\d{10}|)  gives 1234567890`

But

- `((?=\d{16}$)\d{10}$|) does not give 7890123456`

basically, I want last 10 digits *if* it is compulsory 16 digit no *else* nothing.

Comment: Can you just do `\d{6}(\d{10})`?

Comment: This gives entire 16 digit number.

Comment: If the string is of fixed length and you know beforehand it only consists of digits, just use substring.

Comment: @ShekharSutar - Extract [capture group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg) #1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want validation and extraction within single regex.

Comment: From a nitwit `((?=\d{10}$)\d{10}$|)` - I interprete the first part: the last ten digits (dollar=end), and the result (the right half) is its ten digits.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : having any sample regex?

Comment: @ShekharSutar - I just gave you one :/

Comment: See https://ideone.com/6Nv1jG

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : regex does not validate if it is a 16 digit number https://ideone.com/Sw4igM

Comment: @ShekharSutar That is easily adjustable: use [`"\\d{6}(\\d{10})"`](https://ideone.com/5P9zeQ) with `matches()`.

Comment: @anubhava : that giving me entire 16 digit number. I want to extract only last 10 digits.

Comment: @anubhava : Not using java here :( . I want it completely regex based

Comment: You tagged your question as Java. What regex tool are you using?

Comment: @anubhava : If you check my 1st regex, it is giving correct result for first 10 digits of 16 digit number.

Comment: That is not what I asked. What regex tool/flavor are you using?

Comment: @anubhava : tibco bw

Comment: If it supports lookbehind assertion then use `(?<=^\d{6})\d{10}$`

Comment: @anubhava : It worked , You are awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok posted an answer below with demo and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not using Java and cannot use capture groups.

For your tibco tool you can use this regex with validation of 16 digits to grab last 10 digits:

```
(?<=^\d{6})\d{10}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXiukm/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=^\d{6})` is a positive lookbehind to assert that we have 6 digits from start to previous position
- `\d{10}$` matched 10 digits at the end of string

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How to extract last X digits from fixed Y digit number using RegEx?

.{X}$

where X is number of digits you want to extract

Comment: That's not going to work. last 10 digits if it is compulsory 16 digit number else nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tpresy/1) that the regex `^\d{6}(\d{10})$` will check if there is 16digit from start to end of the `String` (so check the length) and capture the last 10.

- `^` : start of the String
- `\d{6}` : first 6 digit
- `(\d{10})` : capture 10 digit
- `$` : end of the String

So you can use it in Java with

```
String s = "1234567890123456";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{6}(\\d{10})$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This can be checked on this [ideone](https://ideone.com/b4UXt5)

You just have to add an `else` clause to print that the `String` is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

given string `" hello 00001234567890 hello"`
then  `\d{10}\b`
will give you the last 10 digits in the number even if the number is longer than 10 and the string does not end with the number

so `1234567890` will be matched